# Tensorflow TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "lambda_1" (type Lambda)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to build a OC-CNN, but when I try to load my model, it meets error

```
def get_model(train=True):
    
    pre_process = Lambda(preprocess_input)
    vgg = VGG16(weights = 'imagenet', include_top = False)
    vgg = Model(vgg.input, vgg.output)
    vgg.trainable = False
    
    inp = Input(SHAPE)
    vgg_16_process = pre_process(GaussianNoise(0.1)(inp))
    vgg_out = vgg(vgg_16_process)
    
    if train:
        noise = Lambda(tf.zeros_like)(vgg_out)
        noise = tf.keras.layers.GaussianNoise(0.1)(noise)
        x = Lambda(lambda z: tf.concat(z, axis=0))([vgg_out,noise])
        x = Activation('relu')(x)
    else:
        x = vgg_out
  
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
    out = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = Model(inp, out)

    return model
```

and I train it via these

```
epochs = 500
model = get_model()
crossentropy = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4) # 1e-4 = 1 * 10^-4 = 0.0001

# make fake label
y_withfakeLabel = list()
y_withfakeLabel.append((1,0)) # positive label
y_withfakeLabel.append((0,1)) # negative label
y_withfakeLabel = tuple(y_withfakeLabel)
y = tf.constant(y_withfakeLabel, dtype = "uint8")

# load data
img = data_loader.get_data()
img = np.expand_dims(img.astype(np.float32), axis=0)
print(img.shape)

for timer in range(epochs):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y_pred = model(img)
        loss = crossentropy(y_true = y, y_pred = y_pred)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
        print("batch %d: loss %f" % (timer, loss.numpy()))
        
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars=zip(grads, model.variables))
```

Then I got a available model and I saved it

```
# Save the model
model.save('OC_CNN_withOnlyOneCat_epoch500.h5')
```

Here I got the warning:
WARNING:tensorflow:Compiled the loaded model, but the compiled metrics have yet to be built. 'model.compile_metrics' will be empty until you train or evaluate the model.
Model: "model_1"

but when I just test loading the model, it encounter this problem:

```
model = load_model('./OC-CNN_withOnlyOneCat_epoch500.h5')


TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [12], line 4
      1 # short test
      2 
      3 # model = load_model('./OC-CNN_withOnlyOneCat_epoch500.h5')
----> 4 model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./OC_CNN_withOnlyOneCat_epoch500.h5')
      6 print(model.summary())
      7 current_dir = os.getcwd()

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py:146, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    141     return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    142 except NameError:
    143   # In some very rare cases,
    144   # `is_traceback_filtering_enabled` (from the outer scope) may not be
    145   # accessible from inside this function
--> 146   return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    148 filtered_tb = None
    149 try:

TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "lambda_1" (type Lambda).

'str' object is not callable

Call arguments received by layer "lambda_1" (type Lambda):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 12, 12, 512), dtype=float32)
  • mask=None
  • training=False
```

and here is my `model.summary()`

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_2 (InputLayer)           [(None, 414, 397, 3  0           []                               
                                )]                                                                
                                                                                                  
 gaussian_noise (GaussianNoise)  (None, 414, 397, 3)  0          ['input_2[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 lambda (Lambda)                (None, 414, 397, 3)  0           ['gaussian_noise[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 model (Functional)             (None, None, None,   14714688    ['lambda[0][0]']                 
                                512)                                                              
                                                                                                  
 lambda_1 (Lambda)              (None, 12, 12, 512)  0           ['model[0][0]']                  
                                                                                                  
 gaussian_noise_1 (GaussianNois  (None, 12, 12, 512)  0          ['lambda_1[0][0]']               
 e)                                                                                               
                                                                                                  
 lambda_2 (Lambda)              (None, 12, 12, 512)  0           ['model[0][0]',                  
                                                                  'gaussian_noise_1[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 activation (Activation)        (None, 12, 12, 512)  0           ['lambda_2[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 flatten (Flatten)              (None, 73728)        0           ['activation[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 dense (Dense)                  (None, 512)          37749248    ['flatten[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 dense_1 (Dense)                (None, 128)          65664       ['dense[0][0]']                  
                                                                                                  
 dense_2 (Dense)                (None, 2)            258         ['dense_1[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 52,529,858
Trainable params: 37,815,170
Non-trainable params: 14,714,688
```

any idea?

Is the cause the warning when I save the model?